# using FPDF and FPDI

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

the root of my website is "/var/www/PDFBuilder". I have 2 folders "fpdf17" and "fpdi142" and i've unzipper a file called "fpdf_tpl.php" in the "fpdf17" folder.

This is my code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

define('FPDF_FONTPATH','/var/www/PDFBuilder/fpdf17/');

require('/var/www/PDFBuilder/fpdf17/fpdf.php');
include('/var/www/PDFBuilder/fpdi142/fpdi.php');
```

When I try to open my website, this is the output I get:

> Warning: require_once(fpdf_tpl.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in /var/www/PDFBuilder/fpdi142/fpdi.php on line 27
>   Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'fpdf_tpl.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/PDFBuilder/fpdi142/fpdi.php on line 27

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution.

you can download the PDF_TPL file (PDF_TPL-1.2.1.zip) from http://www.setasign.de/support/manuals/fpdi/fpdi/

Just extract it and put it in the same folder as the fpdi and you will be fine.

Comment: Thank you for contributing. Perhaps you can try explaining briefly about the link you have posted. It would be helpful at a glance

Answer (score 0):

Use relative paths, for instance, if your code is within fpdf17, your requires should be:

```
require('fpdf.php');
require('../fpdi142/fpdi.php');
```

Comment: require('./fpdf17/fpdf.php');
require('./fpdi142/fpdi.php');

That didnt work neither