# Install FPDI on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php, fpdf, fpdi

I just ran `apt-get install libfpdi-php` as well as installed composer and ran `composer require setasign/fpdi-fpdf`. all three operations seemed to complete swimmingly well however is still get the error when calling `require_once('fpdi.php');` in my PHP script (which is line 3, after calling `require_once ('fpdf.php');`:

`PHP Warning:  require_once(fpdi.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /fpdfwriteon.php on line 3
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'fpdi.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /fpdfwriteon.php on line 3`

I've searched my entire disk for "fpdi" and nothing returns. Am I missing a step? Did I do something wrong with composer?

thanks.

EDIT: I have a link to fpdf.php in /usr/share/php/ from when I installed fpdf but there is no indication of fpdi anywhere

Comment: Are you sure you're not forgetting the include the namespace?

`require_once "fpdi/fpdi"` for example.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011400/using-fpdf-and-fpdi

Comment: I think that link has changed since '13. That referenced file isn't in the manual. just strange that fpdi.php doesn't exist after install (searched in / using WinSCP), thus no way to include it in my script. That post at least had the php file available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this link : https://www.devmanuals.net/install/ubuntu/ubuntu-16-04-LTS-Xenial-Xerus/how-to-install-libfpdi-php.html

You can verify the installation by running the following command.

```
user@demo:/$ dpkg -L libfpdi-php
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/php
/usr/share/php/fpdi
/usr/share/php/fpdi/fpdi.php
/usr/share/php/fpdi/fpdi2tcpdf_bridge.php
/usr/share/php/fpdi/fpdi_pdf_parser.php
/usr/share/php/fpdi/pdf_context.php
/usr/share/php/fpdi/pdf_parser.php
/usr/share/php/fpdi/filters
/usr/share/php/fpdi/filters/FilterASCII85.php
/usr/share/php/fpdi/filters/FilterASCII85_FPDI.php
/usr/share/php/fpdi/filters/FilterLZW.php
/usr/share/php/fpdi/filters/FilterLZW_FPDI.php
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libfpdi-php
/usr/share/doc/libfpdi-php/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libfpdi-php/changelog.Debian.gz
```

When you calling fpdi.php, just give full path in include function.

```
include('/usr/share/php/fpdf.php');
include('/usr/share/php/fpdi/fpdi.php');
```

Comment: this one was a combination of things, mostly my own silly oversight (didn't refresh WinSCP thus even my searches failed... oddly enough). I marked this one correct because the `dpkg -L` command woke me up and the full path is required in `require_once`. I ended up creating a link in /usr/share/php/ to reduce future typing. Cheers!